# Click a Canopy WebElement

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

I have a button that I am retrieving with canopy like this...

```
let buttons = elements ".buttonClass"
```

The last button is the one I want to click, but when I do...

```
click buttons.tail
```

I get an error that says

> "Can't click [OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement] because it is
>   not a string or webelement"

So my question is, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list that's returned with `elements (selector)` is an `IWebElement List`

So, by accessing the list with `buttons.Item (buttons.Length - 1)` I am able to access the `WebElement` object which has a click function on it.

```
let buttons = elements ".buttonClass"
(buttons.Item (buttons.Length - 1)).Click()
```

[Documentation for RemoteWebElement](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebElement.htm)

[Canopy API Documentation](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/reference/canopy-csharp-canopy.html)

Comment: I suggest using `List.last buttons` or `buttons |> List.last`; it's a little easier to read. And easier to read, in the long run, means fewer bugs.

Answer (score 4):

`buttons.tail` is not the "last button", but a list consisting of all buttons but the first one. That's what "tail" normally means in relation to lists. Try this:

```
let list = [1;2;3]
let tail = list.Tail   // tail = [2;3]
```

To get the last element of an F# list, use the `List.last` function:

```
let buttons = elements ".buttonClass"
click (List.last buttons)
```

Comment: What appeals to you the most: the awkward syntax or the inefficiency of traversing the list twice?

Comment: I was going to accept this answer but your comment seems a little snide. Thanks for your input.

Comment: _Your_ original comment (the one you've just removed) was "a little snide". This was my response.

Comment: @Anthony Russell, just curious, what was your comment?

Comment: I said I was going to go with my response but thank you... I don't think that was snide at all. I was being honest that I was accepting my response over yours. I hope that clarifies things. Thanks